# ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [6], [6]

Tags: tensorflow

the error:

ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [6], [6].

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
print(sess.run(c))
```

I don't know what's wrong. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What result did you expect?

Comment: multiply a and b.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.matmul` multiplies matrix, tensors with 2 dimensions. You're trying to multiply, using matmul, two vectors that are tensors with 1 dimension.

Your expected outcome is `[ 1.  4.  9. 16. 25. 36.]` that's the elementwise multiplication of the vector elements. To obtain it, you have to use the `tf.multiply` op.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], name="a")
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], name="b")
c = tf.multiply(a, b)

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
print(sess.run(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise if you want to do a Matrix multiplication, and not elementwise, as suggested in other answers, you need the vectors to be 2D to multiple a row-vector by a column-vector:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([[1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0], [5.0], [6.0]], name="a") # Shape [6, 1]
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]], name="b") # Shape [1, 6]
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) print(sess.run(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.expand_dims(a,0) and tf.expand_dims(b,1) to have rank 2 shapes.
Try the following code:

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(a,0), tf.expand_dims(b, 1))
c2=tf.squeeze(c)
sess=tf.Session()
print(sess.run(c))
print(sess.run(c2))enter code here
```

It will display:

```
[[ 91.]]
91.0
```